# Scanning two integers separated by an unknown character

Tags: python

I want to scan two integers in python that are separated by a character(any character, not only white space).

In C I can just use 
`scanf("%d%c%d",&a,&b,&c);`

Is there something similar I can do in Python?

Comment: Look up regular expressions.

Comment: Pardon me [I am not a `python` guy], but did you not find an already existing answer?

Comment: I think `split` will do that if called without arguments and the delimiter is something like a comma, or a colon a semi colon a whitespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use `re.split()` for this:

```
In [9]: re.split(r'\D', '1024x768')
Out[9]: ['1024', '768']
```

or, if you also need to capture the separating character:

```
In [11]: re.split(r'(\D)', '1024x768')
Out[11]: ['1024', 'x', '768']
```

(In both cases, apply `int()` to the strings to convert them to integers.)

Answer (score 1):

There's no such a feature in Python. You can get the String as is, and check if it's valid by regex or using [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) or any other function.